# How to receive push notification from other apps in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to receive  push notification from other apps in iOS ? Can it be implemented?

Comment: if you have a push-server and could call the API from your app then you could send any notification towards the app in your authority; clean and obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only send push notifications to your own App with your entitlements.

Receiving notifications is not something you do yourself, it's built into iOS, so you have no control over it. This is done specifically to avoid what you're trying to do.